# DocumentDB - Assign collections to different regions

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

This doesn't seem possible via the Azure Portal, but perhaps I overlooked something...

DocumentDB supports only one "write region", but 0..N read regions (i.e. I assume this means 1 primary and N replicas are possible in DB terms). But this seems to be applied to the WHOLE Database. I wonder if it's possible to specify that I want some Collections to have different primary locations (i.e. each collection would have a different write region)?

If this was possible, I could use DocDB's application-level partitioning to direct my reads and writes to the appropriate Collection. The partitioning scheme I would use would be location-aware (e.g. an obvious scheme would involve a "/region" attribute on the document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of DocumentDB only allows choosing write region at an account level.

Having said that, instead of creating multiple collection in a single account,  it is possible to achieve this scenario today using multiple accounts each hosting one collection with desired write region configuration.

There are additional patterns you can employ here to achieve multi-region writes for a single logical collection without requiring any location lookup.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot set a write region for an individual collection. The account has one as you said. That one region allows write and read, the others are read-only replicas. You can find more in this [documentation article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-distribute-data-globally/).